# Как узнать GPS координаты пользователя который зашел с компьютера?

Tags: php, gps

Хочу показать на сайте (php) местонахождение пользователя. Как можно наиболее точно узнать координаты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попросите пользователя ввести свои координаты :) А вообще, для этого есть такая вещь как IP GeoLocation. Копайте по этому ключевому слову. Но имейте в виду, что данные, полученные таким способом не точны и вообще могут не соответствовать действительности.

Кроме того, некоторые браузеры умеют предоставлять такие данные.. и опять же ключевое слово GeoLocation. Например, [geo-location-javascript](http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/). И опять же нет никаких гарантий точности.

Comment: ну можно предоставить пользователю полученные данные, если не соответствуют попросить ввести его вариант. Но врятли все пользователи знают свои координаты в данный момент :))

Comment: Вообще, на работе IP geolocation обычно у людей показывает фантастику.. особенно в международных компаниях. А дома по крайней мере город определяет правильно. Обычного этого достаточно, если вы не собираетесь ракету запускать по заданным координатам.

Comment: Блин, ну теперь не собираюсь :)
Буду рыть апи гуглокарт :) Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

В презентации по HTML5 на сайте вот этих ребят:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/
видел компонент html5 который показывает твое текущее местоположение, по ip есессно, посмотри как сделан компонент или используй сам этот компонент, инфа по адаптации кода для браузеров там тоже есть, но вполне вероятно что, конкретно данный компонент и так заработает во всех браузерах.

Есть еще вариант воспользоваться Google Maps API или Yandex Maps API
Схема проста:
1) Пользователь вводит свой адрес, страну там, город и тп, (или выбирает адрес из выпадающих менюшек)         
2) Карта может показать где это место, и так же карта может дать тебе ГеоКоординаты точки, что, на сколько я знаю, соответсвует gps координатам.